# Sequelize bulkCreate returns incorrect value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

And do not tell me? I use the PostgreSQL base. I have a field code which the trigger before is filled automatically if null.
in sequelize create() works as it should and returns an entry with automatically inserted code.

```
const response = await models.Cartridge.create(
    { quantity, active, code: null },
    { returning: true }
  );

  // dataValues: {id: 5, quantity: 500, active: true, code: "090217205", updatedAt: Fri Jul 19 2019 16:35:59 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), …}
```

and here, bulkCreate () returns a code with the value that we sent to the server (null), and not the fact that it was actually inserted.

```
const response = await models.Cartridge.bulkCreate(
    [{ quantity, active, code: null }],
    { returning: true }
  );

  // [ { dataValues: {id: 7, code: null, quantity: 500, active: true, createdAt: Fri Jul 19 2019 16:48:27 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer T }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding individualHooks. Downside is that will do single saves.

```
const response = await models.Cartridge.bulkCreate(
[{ quantity, active, code: null }],
{ returning: true, individualHooks: true});
```